# Returning sum from function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL table where I store the daily intake of water for the users. I want to select the user's intake for the current date. I think I am doing it right, just don't know how to return the number:

```
function intake_so_far(){
    $connection=get_db();
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    $datetoday=date("Y-m-d");
    $sql="SELECT SUM(intake_amount) FROM intake WHERE intake_email='$email' AND date(intake_date)='$datetoday'";
    $q=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
}
```

How should I return the `SUM` of (intake_amount) AS `$intake_so_far`?

Hope you get what I want, huge thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you get now?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp use mysqli_fetch_array to get your result. and return your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the SUM of `(intake_amount)` in `$intake_so_fa` as:

```
function intake_so_far()
{
    $connection = get_db();
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    $datetoday=date("Y-m-d");
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(intake_amount) AS intake_so_far FROM intake WHERE intake_email = '$email' 
    AND DATE(intake_date) ='$datetoday'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $intake_so_far = $row['intake_so_far'];
    return $intake_so_far; // return sum of this value
}
```

You can use `mysqli_fetch_array` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc` function for getting values.

In this example, i have used `mysql_fetch_array` because `mysqli_fetch_array()` function fetches a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both. (Line fetch from W3School)

And `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will return you only associative array in result.

Answer (score 1):

```
function intake_so_far(){
    $connection=get_db();
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    $datetoday=date("Y-m-d");
    $sql="SELECT SUM(intake_amount) AS intake_so_far FROM intake WHERE intake_email='$email' AND date(intake_date)='$datetoday'";
    $res=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    return $row['intake_so_far'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function intake_so_far(){
$connection=get_db();
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$datetoday=date("Y-m-d");
$sql="SELECT SUM(intake_amount) FROM intake WHERE intake_email='$email' AND date(intake_date)='$datetoday'";
$q=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
$getSum = mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $getSum[0];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
check out the tutorial in reference to mysqli_fetch_array.